# Couldn't receive values in destination step using ExecutionContextPromotionListener

Tags: spring-batch

I want to pass some information from one step to another step in a batch job. Created BStepListener where the value into the context is stored, but this same value is not coming to tasklet [SendMailTasklet] created in another step. Where am i missing?

Job configuration

```
 <job id="bJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
   <step id="step1">
      <tasklet>
          <chunk reader="bReader" writer="bWriter" processor="bProcessor" 
        commit-interval="10" />
  </tasklet>
 <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="sendEmail"/>
 <listeners>
        <listener ref="bStepListner"/>
        <listener ref="bPromotionListener"/>
 </listeners>
</step>
<step id="sendEmail">
    <tasklet ref="sendMailManager"/>
</step>
</job>
<bean id="bStepListner" class="com.listener.BStepListener" scope="step"/>
<bean id="bPromotionListener" class="org...ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
    <property name="keys" value="msg"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sendMailManager" class="com.mail.SendMailTasklet" scope="step">
```

BStepListener.java

```
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    System.out.println("Step Execution Listener ... after Step");
    String message = "A Sample message from step to step";
    stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("msg", message);
    return null;
}
```

SendMailTasklet.java

```
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)
        throws Exception {
    logger.info("Sending Email service....");

    String message = (String)chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext().get("msg");
    this.sendMail();
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think (I'd have to double check the code) that we don't guarantee the order listeners are called.  Because of that, the promotion listener may be being called before yours is.  Try using the `CompositeStepExecutionListener` to wrap your list of listeners so that order is preserved.

You can read more about the `CompositeStepExecutionListener` here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/CompositeStepExecutionListener.html